# How to import nested dictionaries from a plist in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, plist

I'm a total noob with Swift, but I feel like this has to be possible, and that someone has done it before me.

Here's my problem:
I have a `plist` with a bunch of character classes in a game. Each character levels up uniquely. Ideally I would make the `Level_Progression` an array with 10 sub-dictionaries within the character class dictionary I'm importing from a `plist`. So as the character levels up, the app looks at the `Level_Progression` breakdown to update some fields based on the character's level.

### Here's the question:

How do I import my nested array and sub-dictionaries so my app will understand the relationships of the data?

Here is the plist with some place holder data, formatted in the way I think I want it for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>ClassName</key>
        <string>Barb</string>
        <key>Level_Progression</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>4</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>9</integer>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>ClassName</key>
        <string>Cleric</string>
        <key>Level_Progression</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>3</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>4</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Level</key>
                <integer>5</integer>
                <key>HP_Mult</key>
                <integer>9</integer>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

And here is what my import script looks like right now, which I know isn't working. I have this in a separate swift file, then the plan is to just call the `struct` from the `ViewController` once I have all the data imported

```
import Foundation
struct CharClass {
    let className: String
    let level_Progress: Array<Dictionary<String, Int>>
    let level: Dictionary<String, Int>.Element
    let hp_Mult: Dictionary<String, Int>.Element




    static func classesList(_ fileName: String) -> [CharClass] {
        var charClasses = [CharClass]()

        if let classList = NSArray(contentsOfFile: fileName) as? [[String: Any]] {
            for dict in classList {
                if let charClass = CharClass(dictionary: dict) {
                    charClasses.append(charClass)
                }
            }
        }
        return charClasses
    }




    init?(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        guard let className = dictionary["ClassName"] as? String,
            let level_Progress = dictionary["Level_Progress"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Int>>,
            let level = dictionary["Level"] as? Dictionary<String, Int>.Element,
            let hp_Mult = dictionary["HP_Mult"] as? Dictionary<String, Int>.Element else {
                return nil
        }

        self.className = className
        self.level_Progress = level_Progress
        self.level = level
        self.hp_Mult = hp_Mult
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to write the code to loop through all of the data, populating appropriate structs. Personally, I would use `Codable`  See https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-swift-codable-with-property-lists/

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks, I ended up flattening the plist and splitting it to make it easier to work with in some cases I hadn't considered at first.